# Overload functions for different type arguments?

Tags: c++, operators, overloading

I'm thinking about overload functions, isn't it a faster way to perform, in example, addiction without define the function a lot of times with different arguments and outputs (int, float double ecc...).

more comprehensible:

```
// 2 ints addiction

int addic(int & a, int & b) {
  int c;
  c = a + b;
  return c;
}

// 1 int + 1 float

float addic(int & a, float & b) {
  float c;
  c = a + b;
  return c;
}
```

Isn't a faster way? Have I to define all cases?

Comment: Any specific programming language ?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? I'm having a hard time understanding what you're comparing overloading to.

Comment: Operators overloading ? Are you talking about C++ ?

Comment: Sorry the question wasn't well written!

Comment: "Isn't a faster way?" Are you asking whether there's a faster way than what you have written or whether what you have written is faster than something else? If the latter: faster than what? Also when you say faster, are you talking about performance or programming speed?

Comment: I'm talking about not to write the function so many times!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (to avoid code repetition) is one of the things templates exist for; Here's an example of how you can implement the function you used as an example (in C++11):

```
#include <type_traits> // for std::common_type
template<class T1, class T2>
std::common_type<T1, T2>::type addic(const T1& a, const T2& b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

`T1` will be the type of the first argument you pass to the function, while `T2` will be the type of the second argument.

`std::common_type<T1, T2>::type` is a type that both T1 and T2 can be converted to. For example, if you add a `float` and an `int`, the type will be `float`.

EDIT: If you want to do something with vectors, you can do something like this:

```
template<class T>
void MyFunction(std::vector<T>& v)
{
    // do something with the vector v, for example:
    v.push_back(5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! Good, will it works also if I have vectors (which are just templates) as argouments?

Comment: @Tommaso Ferrari Yes it will work, if you do it the right way.

Comment: However, if I want the addiction of an int with a float that returns a float, is it possible with a template?

Comment: I have some problems, although I set -std=C++11 in compiler_options->settings->code_generation (I use dev-c) results:    #ifndef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
#error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be \
enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
#endif